# How to include Find Duplicates standard button in visualforce page

Tags: apex, commandbutton, findduplicates

I have a requirement to me include standard find duplicates button in the visualforce page like standard save & delete buttons.

I have no clue either we need to create a custom button or there any standard functionality is available.

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top">
  <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Edit, Lead.Id, null, true)}" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Delete, Lead.Id, null, true)}" value="Delete" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Convert, Lead.Id, null, true)}" value="Convert" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Clone, Lead.Id, null, true)}" value="Clone" />
  <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.Share, Lead.Id, null, true)}" value="Sharing" />
  </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [VF developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm?search_text=FindDup) it would be `FindDup`

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Lead.FindDup, Lead.Id, null, true)}" value="FindDup" />
```